# Filtering data older than 10 minutes

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

In MySQL I can use:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

for filtering less than 10 minutes.

How to do that in PostgreSQL? The created at in style "2018-09-27 12:11:32".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from mytable 
where created_at < now()::timestamp - INTERVAL '10 min'
```